# MongoDB Find If Date Today Falls Between Two Columns

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, filter

I'm getting unexpected results for getting the collections between two columns. I have this simple collection:

```
{
  UserID: "1",
  StartDate: "2021-04-15",
  EndDate: "2022-01-18"
}

{
  UserID: "1",
  StartDate: "2022-04-01",
  EndDate: "2022-04-30"
}
```

Now, I want to filter the result by the current date. Today is 2022-04-01 so the expected result would be only:

```
{
  UserID: "1",
  StartDate: "2022-04-01",
  EndDate: "2022-04-30"
}
```

Using this filter is not working as expected:

```
{ 
  UserID: "1",
  StartDate: {
    "$gte": '2022-04-01',
  }, 
  EndDate: {
    "$lte": '2022-04-01',
  }
}
```

As I'm getting no result. Using only EndDate $lte filter is not working properly. Need inputs. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, what's the type for `StartDate` & `EndDate` in MongoDB document? Is it string or DateTime type?

Comment: @YongShun Hello, thanks for the response. It is string for both of those fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({
  UserID: "1",
  StartDate: {
    "$lte": "2022-04-01",
    
  },
  EndDate: {
    "$gte": "2022-04-01"
  }
})
```

Comment: your query is wrong. simply replace your query gte to lte

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/R1ODnqTrevd

Comment: Awesome! It's working now. Can you please explain why is it the other way around? Why should it be $lte on StartDate and $gte on the EndDate?

Comment: EndDate is big to today's date so we have to add $gte